# Gui getter and setter method

Tags: user-interface, panel, getter-setter, class-variables

I'm a beginner java student currently working a gui assignment that involves calculating purchases made at a auto motive garage, I have the majority complete but I'm stuck when making a summary panel class.The first block of code is my handler class without issues and the next is the summary both include the needed imported packages, I can't seem to figure out how to pass on the variable values from the handler to the summary page and assign them to the textFields. I apologize in for the format of this post it is in fact my first. If needed I can provide the code from my other panels

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * Contains the event handling code to run the calculation and exit button functions

public class JoesAutoHandler implements ActionListener
{
// instance variables of the JoesAutoGUI and Tax rate
private final double TAX_RATE = 0.07;
protected JoesAutoGUI gui;    

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class EventHandler
 */
public JoesAutoHandler(JoesAutoGUI gui)
{
    // initialize instance of gui referencing the JoesAutoGUI
    this.gui = gui;
}

/**
 * method called when the buttons are clicked
 * performs the required total calculations when the calcButton is clicked
 * closes program when exit button is clicked
 *       
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //variables used within this method
        double subTotal,
               totalTax = 0,
               routineCharge = 0,
               nonRoutineCharge = 0,
               totalCharges = 0;
        int    totalCustomers = 0,
               response;
    
    //sets the values decimal formats           
    DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00");
        
    // method runs when the calcButton is clicked
    if(e.getSource() == gui.calcButton)
    {  
        //call method to retrieve the routine charge amount
        routineCharge = gui.routinePanel.getCharges();
        
        //call the getCharges() method to retrieve the non routine charge amount
        nonRoutineCharge = gui.nonRoutinePanel.getCharges();
        
        //calculations for subtotal           
        subTotal = routineCharge + nonRoutineCharge;
        
        //calculates the total tax
        totalTax = subTotal * TAX_RATE;
        
        //calculates the total charges
        totalCharges = subTotal + totalTax;
        
        //Displays the variable values after the calculations in the details window in dollar format            
        response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Total Routine Service Charge:" + dollar.format(routineCharge) + "\n" 
                                          + "Non Routine Service Charge:" + dollar.format(nonRoutineCharge) + "\n"
                                          + "Sub-Total:" + dollar.format(subTotal) + "\n" 
                                          + "Total tax:" + dollar.format(totalTax) + "\n" 
                                          + "Total Charges:" + dollar.format(totalCharges),
                                          "Comfirm Customer Reciept",
                                          JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                          
        //increase the totalCustomer value when the calcButton is clicked
        totalCustomers++;
        
    }
    //if the exitButton is clicked the program will close
    if(e.getSource() == gui.exitButton) System.exit(0);
}
}

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SummaryPanel extends JPanel
{
// instance variables for the labels, text fields and values
protected JLabel totalCustomersLabel,
                 totalRoutineChargesLabel,
                 totalNonRoutineChargesLabel,
                 totalTaxLabel,
                 totalChargesLabel;
protected JoesAutoHandler gui;                 
protected JTextField totalCustomersTextField,
                     totalRoutineChargesTextField,
                     totalNonRoutineChargesTextField,
                     totalTaxTextField,
                     totalChargesTextField;                      
//instance of the summary panel variables
private int totalCustomers;    
private double totalRoutineServiceCharges;    
private double totalNonRoutineServiceCharges;    
private double totalTax;    
private double totalCharges;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class SummaryPanel
 */
public SummaryPanel()
{      
    
   // creates decimal format objects fot the totals variables
   DecimalFormat totalCustomerDf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
   DecimalFormat totalRoutineChargesDf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
   DecimalFormat totalNonRoutineChargesDf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
   DecimalFormat totalTaxDf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
   DecimalFormat totalChargesDf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
   
   //creates the gridLayout with 5 row and 2 columns
   setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));
   
   //creates the label objects and sets the string text
   totalCustomersLabel = new JLabel("Total Customers:");       
   totalRoutineChargesLabel = new JLabel("Total Routine Charges:");
   totalNonRoutineChargesLabel = new JLabel("Total NonRoutine Charges:");
   totalTaxLabel = new JLabel("Total Tax:");       
   totalChargesLabel = new JLabel("Total Charges:");

   //creates the text field components and initalizes them to 0
   totalCustomersTextField = new JTextField("0");
   totalRoutineChargesTextField = new JTextField("0");
   totalNonRoutineChargesTextField = new JTextField("0");
   totalTaxTextField = new JTextField("0");
   totalChargesTextField = new JTextField("0");
         
   totalCustomersTextField.setText("" + totalCustomers);

   //sets the labels to right-justification
   totalCustomersLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
   totalRoutineChargesLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
   totalNonRoutineChargesLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
   totalTaxLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
   totalChargesLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
   
   //sets the textboxes to right-justification
   totalCustomersTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   totalRoutineChargesTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   totalNonRoutineChargesTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   totalTaxTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   totalChargesTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   
   //makes the textboxes read only
   totalCustomersTextField.setEditable(false);
   totalRoutineChargesTextField.setEditable(false);
   totalNonRoutineChargesTextField.setEditable(false);
   totalTaxTextField.setEditable(false);
   totalChargesTextField.setEditable(false);             
   
   //adds components to the panel
    add(totalCustomersLabel);
    add(totalCustomersTextField);
    add(totalRoutineChargesLabel);
    add(totalRoutineChargesTextField);
    add(totalNonRoutineChargesLabel);
    add(totalNonRoutineChargesTextField);                
    add(totalTaxLabel);
    add(totalTaxTextField);       
    add(totalChargesLabel);     
    add(totalChargesTextField);
    
    //converts the variable data types to String 
    String totalCustomersText = Integer.toString(totalCustomers);
    String totalRoutineServiceChargesText = Double.toString(totalRoutineServiceCharges);
    String totalNonRoutineServiceChargesText = Double.toString(totalNonRoutineServiceCharges);
    String totalTaxText = Double.toString(totalTax);
    String totalChargesText = Double.toString(totalCharges);
    
    //sets the component text fields with the variable values
    totalCustomersTextField.setText(totalCustomersText);
    totalRoutineChargesTextField.setText(totalRoutineServiceChargesText);
    totalNonRoutineChargesTextField.setText(totalNonRoutineServiceChargesText);
    totalTaxTextField.setText(totalTaxText);
    totalChargesTextField.setText(totalChargesText);
}

/**
 *get set methods for all variables
 */
public int getTotalCustomers()
{
    // returns total customers
    return totalCustomers;
}

public void setTotalCustomers(int totalCustomers)
{
    //set total customers
    this.totalCustomers = totalCustomers;
}

public double getTotalRoutineServiceChargess()
{
    // gets totalRoutineServiceCharges
    return totalRoutineServiceCharges;
}

public void setTotalRoutineServiceCharges(double totalRoutineServiceCharges)
{
    //sets totalRoutineServiceCharges
    this.totalRoutineServiceCharges = totalRoutineServiceCharges;
}

public double getTotalNonRoutineCharges()
{
    //gets totalNonRoutineServiceCharges
    return totalNonRoutineServiceCharges;
}

public void setTotalNonRoutineServiceCharges(double totalNonRoutineServiceCharges)
{
    //sets totalNonRoutineServiceCharges
    this.totalNonRoutineServiceCharges = totalNonRoutineServiceCharges;
}

public double getTotalTax()
{
    // gets total Tax
    return totalTax;
}

public void setTotalTax(double totalTax)
{
    //set total tax
    this.totalTax = totalTax;
}

public double getTotalCharges()
{
    // gets total charges
    return totalCharges;
}

public void setTotalCharges(double totalCharges)
{
    //sets total charges 
    this.totalCharges = totalCharges;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see where the issue is, I needed to write the code to set the summary text fields within handler class and make a reference object for the summary class.